# How to Download Input Text from user as PDF using HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to take input from the user using the < input > tag and when the user clicks on download button, then then the input gets downloaded as pdf. How Can I implement it using HTML, CSS and Javascript on the client side.

Comment: You can use jsPDF to generate PDF from your text.

Comment: I am facing some problems while using JS PDF. Like here:  doc.text(10, 10, text.value); you took 10,10 so If I write Hello World it getting Printed in PDF fine but if user input is very large like lorem epsum .... then only some part(till it can adjust in one line) get printed on pdf rest gets overflow and not printed. I want them to be continued from next line if current line gets filled. What Changes do I need to make.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [jsPDF library](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) to generate PDFs.

You can add text via the `text()` method and save via the `save()` method.

To ensure the text wraps, we can use `splitTextToSize` to convert it to an array and pass it as a parameter to the `text()` method:

```js
download.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var doc = new jsPDF()
  doc.text(10, 10, doc.splitTextToSize(text.value, 180));
  doc.save('doc.pdf');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.min.js"></script>

<input id="text"><button id="download">Download as PDF</button>
```

Try it on [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Spectric/8w0ys1zv/)

Comment: I am facing some problems while using JS PDF. Like here:  doc.text(10, 10, text.value); you took 10,10 so If I write Hello World it getting Printed in PDF fine but if user input is very large like lorem epsum .... then only some part(till it can adjust in one line) get printed on pdf rest gets overflow and not printed. I want them to be continued from next line if current line gets filled. What Changes do I need to make.

Comment: @PranshuKashyap I've updated my answer and JsFiddle. It should work now.

Comment: Yeah, the previous problem is solved, text is continuing from next line rather than overflowing. But Again the Problem is when text.value exceeds one page it trims the text and limits upto there. I wanted it to get continued from next page.